# getActionBar() returns Null (AppCompat-v7 21)

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-appcompat

My app is crashing the minute I run it after I changed my AppCompat-v7 to 21.0.0 and Compiled with no problem.

It gives me the error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.app.ActionBar.setIcon(int)' on a null object reference
```

on this line:

```
getActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_bar);
```

It works with AppCompat-v7 20.0.0, but not with 21.0.0.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

You need to call [`getSupportActionBar()` on an `ActionBarActivity`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarActivity.html#getSupportActionBar%28%29). Do not call `getActionBar()` -- that is not available on older devices, and for the new r21 edition of `appcompat-v7`, I would expect it to return `null` all the time, as the new `ActionBarActivity` disables and replaces the system action bar.

Comment: in addition to this, you have to make sure toolbar is added into our layout and you are calling `setSupportActionBar(yourToolBar)`

Comment: There is no getSupportActionBar in my ActionBarActivity

Comment: @DalvikVM: There should be: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarActivity.html#getSupportActionBar%28%29

Comment: @CommonsWare: sorry my mistake. I was looking at a fragment where I added my own `getActionbar()` which returned `this.getActivity().getActionBar()`. Notice that when you want to access it from a fragment you have to cast `getActivity()` to `ActionBarActivity`.

Comment: This would be a more complete answer: `((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_bar);`

Answer (score 11):

If your activity is AppCompatActivity, you can get the action bar like this:

```
android.support.v7.app.ActionBar mActionBar = getSupportActionBar();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Object actionBar = getSupportActionBar();

android.support.v7.internal.app.WindowDecorActionBar bar = (android.support.v7.internal.app.WindowDecorActionBar) actionBar;
```

If you are developing app targeting 21SDK but app is going to be used under older sdk's then this lines above are the solution.

You can't use getActionBar() under 21SDK when your activity extends ActionBarActivity

Answer (score 0):

Replace ActionBar by  android.support.v7.app.ActionBar in all you code. and use setSupportActionBar() also Extent your activity from AppCompatActivity. use android support v7 dependency.