# Calling New Activity From ActionBar

Tags: java, android, android-activity

When attempting to call a new activity (settings) from the action bar, I get the error `java.lang.NullPointerException`. I'm not too sure where I'm going wrong, below is the code I am using. Everything compiles fine, when I test the application and press the "Settings" button, the app then crashes.

**MainActivity.java**

```
package liam.lbee.com.test1;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;



public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),SettingsActivity.class));
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

**Menu_Main.xml**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" tools:context=".MainActivity">



    <item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        app:showAsAction="never" />


</menu>
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="liam.lbee.com.test1" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".SettingsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_settings"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="liam.lbee.com.test1.MainActivity" />
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**LogCat Files**

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{liam.lbee.com.test1/liam.lbee.com.test1.SettingsActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2292)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2350)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:163)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1257)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5335)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at liam.lbee.com.test1.SettingsActivity.setupActionBar(SettingsActivity.java:58)
            at liam.lbee.com.test1.SettingsActivity.onCreate(SettingsActivity.java:48)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5389)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2256)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2350)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:163)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1257)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5335)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
```

**setupActionBar (As requested)**

```
private void setupActionBar() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
            // Show the Up button in the action bar.
            getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Which line is giving you the NullPointerException?

Comment: @MFazio23 - **8585-8585/liam.lbee.com.test1 E/ViewRootImpl﹕ sendUserActionEvent() mView == null** is the first error in the log file when testing

Comment: In your logcat, there should be a stack trace that shows the NullPointerException and the class + method in which it occurred:

For example:
*java.lang.NullPointerException
at [Class Name].[Method Name]([File name].java:74)*

Comment: @MFazio23 See updated Question, hope that's what your looking for

Comment: Yep, that's it.  Can you post the *setupActionBar()* method within your SettingsActivity?  The intent to the SettingsActivity works fine, it's the initialization there that fails.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: @njzk2 - The error itself is a duplicate, but how to fix it is not.

Comment: @SilverShotBee - Try using *getSupportActionBar()* instead of *getActionBar()*.  This is assuming your SettingsActivity is extending ActionBarActivity (as your MainActivity is doing)

Comment: @MFazio23: the whole point of the linked question is to explain the debug process so that the OP can get the basic troubleshooting done before asking the question. (Typically to avoid the case where the code where the exception is thrown is only posted after you had to *ask* for it)

Comment: a more exact duplicate would be http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26435231/getactionbar-returns-null-appcompat-v7-21 then

Comment: @njzk2 - The first one was a valid post, I just didn't feel like it was a duplicate.  The second one, however, is exactly on.

Comment: @MFazio23 when I attempt to change it to **getSupportActionBar()** I encounter the error: "Unable to resolve method"

Comment: @SilverShotBee - Make sure your SettingsActivity is extending ActionBarActivity, since that's the class with this method.

Comment: @MFazio23 Thank you. Got there in the end! I'd accept an answer if posted. Cheers

Comment: @SilverShotBee - I added a summary solution for future reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Final summary: The issue was with the SettingsActivity not using the *getSupportActionBar()* method from ActionBarActivity.  Once the class was updated to extend from ActionBarActivity and the called method was changed, this worked.

Another example of this: [getActionBar() returns Null (AppCompat-v7 21)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26435231/getactionbar-returns-null-appcompat-v7-21)