# Android Action Bar Support

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I'm new to android. Been working with these action bars lately.

I used this following code on my mainActivity's onCreat()

```
  import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round);
    }
```

and it works
But if I use this code

```
import android.ActionBar;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round);
    }
```

It creates a `Null pointer exception` at `setDisplayShowHomeEnabled()`.
Due to that the `getActionBar()` returning `Null`.

Can anyone say the reason behind this.?

Thanks.

Comment: Everything in the [accepted answer there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26435242) also applies to `AppCompatActivity`, as that's likely what your `MainActivity` is actually extending.

Comment: Thank You @MikeM.